# set nav tab style class to active if currently in that route react react-router

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-router

I have a react and react-router app using 2 nested routes to deliver 3 total routes: /, /about, /contact.  When I click Link's to go to each route the tab on my nav which is in the parent route changes style and shows its active, some bootstrap magic I believe.  The problem is when I visit /about or /contact, the nav tab is not active.  I am new to react but I am guess I need to bind the style attribute to a condition that checks the property of the route, or props or state of component.  I am not exactly sure how to do this, any help would be very appreciated.

the simplified layout where the nav is

```
export default class Layout extends React.Component {
  render() { 
      return (
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/contact">Contact</Link></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    )}}
```

Where in the < li > I need something like class={if this.props.children == About, class=active, class=""}

the render routes

```
render((
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Layout}>
      <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
      <Route path="/contact" component={Contact}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>
  ), document.getElementById('app'))
```

yea so as noted above the li needs to check if the Layouts props.children is null, or is it about or contact.  I am really not sure how to compare the value of this.props.children if it's a react components

Thanks to all in advanced!!!

Comment: I suggest reading the docs for <Link> https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#link — also, in all of the doc examples the routes `/about` and `contact` (i.e nested ones) forgo the `/`.

Comment: Nice thank you, IndexLink is very useful.  I am not sure what you mean when you say "in all of the doc examples the routes /about and contact (i.e nested ones) forgo the /. " can you elaborate?

Comment: In your code, `path="/about"` etc, it does not match the docs, which specify: `path="about"` (no forward slash), I have seen a few github issues where people have discussed the slash causing problems.

Comment: okay thanks good to know.  still need path="/" for the parent I think.  still can't get the class to be active. think its b/c it sets link to class of active, but bootstrap looks for the < li > element with active class and doesn't make the tab active by the route, only when its click... I think.

Comment: @user1807880 please have a look at the examples in the 1.0.x branch, specifically this one shows exactly what you are trying to do https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/1.0.x/examples/active-links/app.js

Comment: @knowbody thank you, thats a clear example of the index route usage and more, but if I want to apply style or style class to the < li > just outside of the link I can't use anything from react-router right?  I would need to add some logic in myself right?   Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following our conversation in the comments, this is how you would get `active` class name on your `<li>` tags:

*Note: I assume that you are using React Router v1.0.x, I would highly recommend to use the most updated version - 2.0, see [Upgrade Guides](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/upgrade-guides/v2.0.0.md)*

```
import { Link, History } from 'react-router'

const Tab = React.createClass({
  mixins: [ History ],
  render() {
    let isActive = this.history.isActive(this.props.to, this.props.query)
    let className = isActive ? 'active' : ''
    return <li className={className}><Link {...this.props}/></li>
  }
})

// use it just like <Link/>, and you'll get an anchor wrapped in an `li`
// with an automatic `active` class on both.
<Tab href="foo">Foo</Tab>
```

If you are using ES6 classes, you would do it a very similar way, but instead of using mixins you need to "pull" `history` from the context ([here is how to do it](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/1.0.x/docs/API.md#but-im-using-classes) - again this is on the React Router v1.0.x branch).

Comment: but I am still figuring out the mixins in es6.. in particular finding this.history.isActive in the tab component and passing the history to is correctly, and I am using react-router 2.0 and es6

Comment: @user1807880 that's why I said to check the upgrade guide, everything should be in the docs, see: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/upgrade-guides/v2.0.0.md#link-to-onenter-and-isactive-use-location-descriptors If you have more questions I would be happy to help out, get in touch on discord or twitter.